# How do I remove/replace the ⁿ character from a string?

Tags: python, ascii

```
string = "000000ⁿ0000"
    
string.replace('ⁿ', "-")
string.replace('\u207f', "-")
    
print(string)
```

**Error**:

```py
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u207f' in position 6: character maps to <undefined>
```

Explicitly specifying utf-8 didn't help

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entire error message, include the stack trace which shows which line of code caused the error.

Comment: Replace (`.replace('ⁿ', '-')`) seems to work perfectly fine in my Python 3.8 REPL.

Comment: Which version of Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace returns what you want, there is no side effect.

```
string = "000000ⁿ0000"
ok = string.replace('ⁿ','-')
print(string)
#000000ⁿ0000
print(ok)
#000000-0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `encoding` into `Ascii`

```
string = "000000ⁿ0000"
    
output = string.encode('ascii','ignore')
print(output)
```

output

```
'0000000000'
```